# Horizontal auto scroll when using drag and drop column reordering only works once

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid which may have many columns and so I have enabled horizontal scrolling to allow all the columns to be shown.

I need to be able to re-order the columns and am using the Drag and Drop functionality to do so.

This works fine the first time as the selected column can be dragged to end and the grid auto scrolls but once dropped the auto scrolling no longer works for any other column I drag.

I have searched the Kendo documentation & forum and have not found an answer to this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/column-reordering">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.common-fiori.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.fiori.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.fiori.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="example" style='width:400px;'>
        <div id="grid"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "odata",
                        transport: {
                            read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                        },
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                    ShipCountry: { type: "string" },
                                    ShipCity: { type: "string" },
                                    ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                    OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                                    ShippedDate: {type: "date" }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 15
                    },
                    height: 550,                    
                    reorderable: true,  
                    scrollable:true,
                    columns: [
                        {
                            field: "OrderDate",
                            title: "Order Date",
                            width: 120,
                            format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "ShipCountry",
                            title: "Ship Country",
                            width: 120
                        },
                        {
                            field: "ShipCity",
                            title: "Ship City",
                            width: 120
                        },
                        {
                            field: "ShipName",
                            title: "Ship Name",
                            width: 120
                        },
                        {
                            field: "ShippedDate",
                            title: "Shipped Date",
                            format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                            width: 200
                        },
                        {
                            field: "OrderID",
                            title: "ID",
                            width: 80
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does any body have any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To clarify you meant horizontal scrolling no longer works?  When I used Kendo's demo the vertical scrolling seemed to working after the drag and drop reordering.  It sounds like you may have found a bug and you should submit to a support ticket to Telerik to see if they have a fix for it.

If you could post your code that would be helpful as well.  It appears you just posted the Kendo Demo code which does not really help me fix what is wrong with your code.